Special material, colored according to an algorithm UE5
I have a txt file, that stores a set of hex color codes grading from white to black (for example #939393). In editor I have a torus shape. The material of that torus should be divided into squares according to the number of hex color codes in txt file. And these squares need to be colored according to the given information. How to realize that?
Great thanks to everyone!
For example the material need to be colored to smth like that: Material ex
And then that material need to be applied to the torus shape
Torus ex

Where are you stuck?  So far it sounds like you need to focus a little bit.  Right now the answer to "how to realize that" is almost exactly the question:  Read the colors from the txt file, create a material, divide the torus (UVs) into squares, and apply the colors.  What part do you need help with?

@Wyck, great thanks to your response! I'm new to unreal engine 5. I know the basics and how things work, but not deep enough. I'm stuck at the very beginning. I will find the tutorials how to read txt file. But next I need to store my colors somewhere. And then create the material. So I do not know what nodes need to be used to create the material I need
